# How to give validation for jpg or jpeg image using validation control in asp.net

Tags: validation, controls

Can any please help me to place validation for fileupload control to accept only jpg and jpeg image format only using validation control in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Why not to write your own custom validator (server side validation) or a very simple jquery check binded to onclientclick (client validation) ?

Comment: dont want to go for server side validation and jquery too. Only validation control need to use as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\{2}\w+)\$?)(\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpg|.png|.gif)$

use Regular Expression validator.... this as a validation expression

Comment: Hi Jasmine, your code appears to only support Windows file systems.  A more general `(\.jpg|\.jpeg)$` would probably do the trick.